# Text input does not focus in jquery mobile 1.4.0

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a text input and want to focus upon init.  But nothing happens when the code is run.  Any idea?  I am using jquery mobile 1.4.0

```
<input type="text" name="txb" id="txb" value="" data-clear-btn="true" data-mini="true"/>


    <script>
        $('#home').on('pageinit', function () {
            $('#txb').focus();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it in the pageshow event.

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "#page1", function(){
    $('#txb').focus();
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/2NepE/)**